# How do I automatically copy formules from above row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a simple user interface to get user data. It gets a few entries, puts it into the designated database and clears the form. That works fine. While columns 0 to 6 are user data, columns 7 to 11 are formulas using data from 0 to 6. I'm looking for a solution that the user does not have to put in data and then manually needs to copy the above formulas. I don't want to put in the formulas before hand, because I think I will have a problem since the script looks for the last row.

So in short: it needs to find the last row on the sheet, write the data in to a new row and copy formulas in column 7 to 11 from the row above it to the new row. Total noob here, does this make sense?

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var values = [[formSS.getRange("d3").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d5").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d11").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d13").getValue()]]
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,6).setValues(values)

  formSS.getRange("d3").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("d5").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("d7").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("d9").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("d11").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("d13").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: You can use [array formulas](https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/arrayformula-google-sheets/) to do this. It all depends on what formulas you have in columns 7 through 11

Comment: Thanks, but one of the formulas in H10 for example is this: `=IMPORTXML(($B$1&""&B10)&"/","//div[@class='priceValue ']")` I can't get it to work with arrayFormula. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the data you get with `IMPORTXML` is static, it's probably better to replace this formula with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`. This way you will remove a lot of `IMPORTXML` formulas which are constantly updated from your table and it will start working much faster. I think this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615142/phantom-span-element-using-importxml-with-xpath-in-google-spreadsheet) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options for solving your task:

*Option 1:* When generating an array of data for the row to be inserted, you can read the formulas from the previous row and add them to the array before inserting

```
...
  var values = [formSS.getRange("d3").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d5").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d11").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d13").getValue()],
      lastRow = datasheet.getLastRow(),
      formulas = datasheet.getRange(lastRow,7,1,5).getFormulasR1C1();
  
  datasheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,11).setValues([[...values,...formulas[0]]])
...
```

*Option 2.* You can insert formulas directly in the script without reading them from the sheet

```
...
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("d3").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d5").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d11").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d13").getValue(),
                '=FormulaR1C1 for column 7',
                `=IMPORTXML(R1C2&R[0]C[-6]&"/","//div[@class='priceValue ']")`,
                '=FormulaR1C1 for column 9',
                '=FormulaR1C1 for column 10',
                '=FormulaR1C1 for column 11',]]
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(values)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I used option 2. I didn't know about R1C1, really power full. Would you mind if I tagged you in my next question? It will be about combining new entries with existing data from the database.

Comment: Not at all. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253203/how-do-i-combine-new-entries-with-existing-data-from-the-database