# How do I combine new entries with existing data from the database?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a tool for my trades. I have built several functions where I can add new trades to my portfolio and close trades where trades are moved from my portfolio to my archive. But sometimes I buy assets on different prices, like expecting it to go down a bit, but since I don't know how much I ladder down accumulating on different levels. I would like to add those trades to my sheet as well, however that requires the existing asset to update its amount and purchase price.

Here is an example file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGoDwmFmPZa1tifijsPI2aS4L8AXQ0WVNiofpS-xhy8/edit?usp=sharing

There are two sheets, one to submit data and one database. So basically, my first challenge: it should not write on the last row, but the row where the asset already exist. Second challenge: while some data can be just changed to the new info, some needs to be combined with the existing data (old amount + new amount, average purchase price instead of old/new purchase price).

[This is the "trademanager" sheet, you enter a trade and it copies it to the portfolio. What I don't want is a new row with this trade, what I do want is to update the already existing asset with this new trade (add amount, average price, and putting in new date, SL en TP info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMytN.png)

[This is the "porftolio" sheet, with the current situation (duplicate assets) and the desired situation (new and old asset combined with amount added to existing and price averaged between existing and new entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzyiM.png)

This is what I have so far. I know it is something with finding the unique asset and writing to it. But I don't know how to combine it. Or maybe there is a much easier way of course.

```
function updateTrade() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Trademanager");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Portfolio");

  var values = [[formSS.getRange("d3").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d5").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d11").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("d13").getValue(),
                '=if(R[0]C[-3]=1,0,(((R[0]C[-1]/R[0]C[-3]-1)*100)/((R[0]C[-3]/R[0]C[-2]-1)*100)))']]
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7).setValues(values)
}

var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1;

function searchStr(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Trademanager");

  var str = formSS.getRange("d17").getValue();
  Logger.log(str);

  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Portfolio").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if(row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {

      formSS.getRange("d3").setValue(row[0]);
      formSS.getRange("d5").setValue(row[1]);
      formSS.getRange("d7").setValue(row[2]);
      formSS.getRange("d9").setValue(row[3]);
      formSS.getRange("d11").setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("d13").setValue(row[5]);
      formSS.getRange("d25").setValue(row[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I took out the portion I needed help with.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand `There are two sheets, one to submit data and one database.`. And, where can I see the sample input and output situations in your sample Spreadsheet? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question from your provided sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You not understanding the question is probably the lack of my capability to explain. What I meant with two sheets is that there are two sheets in the file, also referred to in the code with: ```var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Trademanager");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Portfolio");``` you can put in a new trade on the sheet named 'trade manager' and see the result on the sheet named 'portfolio' there is also a current and desired example in there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: No thank you for the effort. I made print screen of both sheets. The "trademanager" sheet is to put in a trade, which is copied to "portfolio" sheet with mentioned script. As you can see there is a current situation: duplicate assets (marked pink) and a desired situation (marked green). If you make a trade where you buy the same asset for a different price, I want the amount in my portfolio changed as well as the average price.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. From your provided information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the inputted values from the sheet "Trademanager" and want to put it to the sheet "Portfolio". At this time, you want to search the duplicate values from the column "B" of "Portfolio" and when the inputted value is duplicated with the existing data, you want to put the data by updating.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function updateTrade() {
  // Retrieve Spreadsheet and Sheet objects.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Trademanager");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Portfolio");

  // Retrieve values from D1:D13 and retrieve the specific rows.
  var colValues = formSS.getRange("D1:D13").getValues();
  var values = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13].map(e => colValues[e - 1][0]);

  // Retrieve values from A4:F and create an object.
  var dataRange = datasheet.getRange("A4:F" + datasheet.getLastRow());
  var obj = dataRange.getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    o[r[1] == values[1] ? "dupValues" : "newValues"].push(r);
    return o
  }, { newValues: [], dupValues: [] });

  // Create an array of new values.
  if (obj.dupValues.length > 0) {
    var [, , occ, odd] = obj.dupValues[0];
    var [naa, nbb, ncc, ndd, nee, nff] = values;
    obj.newValues.push([naa, nbb, occ + ncc, ((ndd * ncc) + (odd * occ)) / (occ + ncc), nee, nff]);
  } else {
    obj.newValues.push(values);
  }

  // Overwrite range by the created values.
  dataRange.clearContent();
  datasheet.getRange(4, 1, obj.newValues.length, obj.newValues[0].length).setValues(obj.newValues);
}
```

- When you run this modified script, the inputted values are retrieved from "Trademanager" and the values are checked with "Portfolio" and put to it to "Portfolio".
- The formulas of `occ + ncc` and `((ndd * ncc) + (odd * occ)) / (occ + ncc)` are from your sample Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Hontoni arigato gozaimasu! Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I still need to understand how you did it, but I will try to figure that out. Is it ok if I tag you in another question? It is a bit different. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Osman P. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too. About your new question, when I saw your posted new question, I would like to check it. When I could understand your new question, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but would you mind commenting on each row of your comment on what is happening? It could really help me better to understand and learn. If it's no trouble of course.

Comment: @Osman P. Thank you for replying. About your additional request of `but would you mind commenting on each row of your comment on what is happening?`, I added the comment on my modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: It is very useful, thank you!

Comment: i have put in a follow up question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291382/how-do-i-copy-and-move-certain-parts-of-data-from-one-sheet-to-another